# document.write replace page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever i tried using document.write it replaces the current html page content in example i have this **HTML**

```
 <body>
<div>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

and this **jQuery**

```
var notif = document.write("<div class = 'bg' style = 'height:250px; width:400px; z-index:10; background:red;'>Good Morning!</div>");
 $('body').append(notif).delay(5000).fadeOut()
```

this replace the whole page big Hello will be gone
the jQuery will work after a 5 seconds it disappears then displays nothing?

Comment: Please read [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/4642212).

Comment: alternative use then?

Comment: Read the answers! They tell you an alternative.

Comment: Like Xufox says it's a bad practice and considered obsolete. You could search how to correctly manipulate the DOM. Also `innerHTML` is considered bad code, do a research.

Answer (score 0):

document.write is not needed for 'append' (document.write writes the content to the page replacing the existing content fully). Pls see the documentation for jquery append: http://api.jquery.com/append/

You'll have to just write

```
var notif = "<div class = 'bg' style = 'height:250px; width:400px; z-
index:10; background:red;'>Good Morning!</div>";
$('body').append(notif).delay(5000).fadeOut()
```